# Is it possible to generate SQL script from database-first generated C# classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssms

As title asks, is it possible to generate SQL scripts from C# generated classes?

I had a database-first ASP.NET MVC project, but then I had many BSOD-s and at the end, lost the database and its all configurations. So I simply cannot generate that many tables by hand by looking the C# classes, there are simply too many.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer is NO. 
you should make it manual or change your approach to Code-First.